# Setting Content via Response Object in Components

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Can someone explain to me why the following code isn't outputting anything in a component? Does the response object in a component behave differently from that in an action (since the code works as part of an action)?

I am using Symfony 1.4.

```
$this->getResponse()->setContent("OK");
```

Code block:

```
class merchantComponents extends sfComponents
{
  .....
  public function executeAjaxrcmc(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $company_user_id = $this->getRequestParameter('ids');

    if(($company_user_id>0) && $request->isMethod('post'))
    {               
        $this->getResponse()->setContent("OK");
        return sfView::NONE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setContent("FAIL");
        return sfView::NONE;            
    } 
  }
....
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably need to send the content after setting it:

```
$this->getResponse()->sendContent();
```

Or, output it in a template file.

```
<?php echo $sf_response->getContent(); ?>
```

Comment: Your suggestion works as well as what I had posted originally. I had some other bug that was throwing an error but I was viewing the page in a non-dev view which resulted in a blank page. Yes, I do feel foolish :) Thanks anyway.